# css3 column-width: content falls away when horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css

You can view the issue here:
http://www.callensewout2011.dreamhosters.com/results.php?q=frankrijk

Who knows how to fix this?

```
<div id="result-wrapper">
<a href="article.php?articleId=173&amp;q=frankrijk">
          <div class="tile" id="tile1">
                <div class="tileTextEmpty">
                     <img src="img/logos/hbvl.png" alt="Logo van Het Belang Van Limburg">
                </div>
                <div class="tileText">
                    <h4>Vliegtuig Hollande getroffen door bliksem </h4>
                    <p>De kersverse nieuwe Franse president François Hollande heeft dinsdag voor het eerst de Duitse kanselier Angela Merkel ontmoet. Hollande moest zijn reis naar Duitsland wel even...</p>
                </div>
          </div>
     </a>
</div>

#result-wrapper {
    -webkit-column-width: 340px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
    height: 649px;
    width: 1024px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: 
    black;
}

.tile {
    height: 325px;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 340px;
    background-color: 
    black;
}

.tileTextEmpty {
    width: inherit;
    height: 155px;
    text-align: left;
}

.tileText {
    height: 135px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .8;
    color: #EAEAEA;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a hbox module. it may helps:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/css-3-flexible-box-model

Comment: But the flexible box model doesnot work other than mozilla and webkit browsers

Comment: @Ravi so does the column and in fact flexible box module is supported by IE10. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Good that IE is bringing it at last after all the browser giants have implemented long back:)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you position the content using display:inline-block or using float:left till the end of the container.

If you don't know how to use display:inline-block see this for your reference

http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/